# MySQL/Percona Server is taking long and I'd prefer to skip all this waiting even if it means data loss

Tags: mysql, innodb, transaction, percona-server, shutdown

*Originally posted to https://www.facebook.com/groups/GNUAndLinux/permalink/10155020539805019/ but no replies received.*

I run Percona Server 5.6.21-70.0-688 x64 on Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS x64, 64GB RAM, 2x2TB SATA* in hardware RAID0 and Intel Xeon E5-1620 v2 3.70GHz. InnoDB/XtraDB is the primary engine (with Barracuda format), with 20GB (21 after recent change) buffer pool size divided to 20 (21 after recent change) pools. The zlib compression is maximized to 9.

The Database Servers and its threads are dropped to nice -20 and ionice -c 1 -n 1.

Almost every Server on rautamiekka.org depends on MySQL databases, especially Minecraft.

I found out how to make a perfect list of IPv4 addresses into a text file. I created a table with auto-increment column and 1 column for each address section, to maximum of 5 columns in total. I made a Python script that started a transaction and explicitly disabled auto-commit and uploaded those addresses. The script had uploaded so many addresses from the 115GB file it had about 51GB of data in, likely already compressed. Then Percona Server 5.6.21-70.1 came out. I thought I'd run the routine update process cuz I thought there'd be no problems so I shutted down Minecraft Servers and any other Server depending on MySQL and forgot about the Python script. However, after fighting with `aptitude` and `apt-get` for few minutes I realized Database Server was still running and not accepting any connections since it was the in the shutdown process. I noticed the Python script had quitted by way or another.

That was Monday 2014-11-24, and the many processes/threads have been running since then, at 20-50KB/s (read) or even 200, and 120-500KB/s (write). It's mainly 1 that runs read and 2 that run write, with 1 process running at least twice as fast as the second, and only 2 processes, mainly, use CPU, but they're not the only ones. I presume it's committing the data into the table and reading the compressed data to verify it.

My estimations say the shutdown will take 9 days if we assume it writes 80GB at 120KB/s at minimum, and I warned ppl it might not be ready until Monday 2014-12-08 although it's been running for days now.

I made changes to the config just recently:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown=1
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup=1
```

I've had

```
[mysqld]
innodb_fast_shutdown = 0
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
```

for ages to ensure InnoDB will write everything before going down so we'll have smaller chances of data loss, but due to that we've had to wait for ages, and probly have to for at least a week, which I hate.

For reference, I posted a change request to MySQL bugs asking for changing the way MySQL handles order to shut down to prevent this kind of downtime: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75110

**What can I do here ? I can consider every method to bring the process down, even loss of data if the loss ain't big, particularly if I lose just a portion of the IPv4 cuz I'll use MySQL script to continue filling up the table. However, I'm afraid I could lose something else, which is almost not an option, but I'll see.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have to let InnoDB purge all its moving parts (Redo Logs, Undo Logs, Dirty Pages, Index Changes, Log Buffer Contents, etc)

Going forward, I recommend the following : Set [innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct) = 0

By default, [innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct) is 75. If you set it to 0, it forces the InnoDB Storage Engine to flush every dirty page and its grandmother out of the InnoDB Buffer Pool without any pausing. It will either flush every page or flush it low enough so that new dirty pages enter the Buffer Pool as fast as old dirty pages are flushed out.

Flushing dirty pages and cleaning up transaction is what consumes the most time in a shutdown. Minimizing the number of pages shortens shutdown time.

You can monitor the following status variables

- [Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty)
- [Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty)

Watch them decrease until it hits zero or levels off. Then, you can issue a shutdown.

Here are additional settings you could use

- Set [innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit) = 2
- Set [innodb_write_io_threads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_write_io_threads) = 64

Give it a Try !!!

## Afterthoughts

Don't worry about dumping the buffer pool map and reloading. The output file is very small.

SATA/RAID0 sound scary to me. You should be using SAS/RAID10 for InnoDB.

At the very least you think about splitting up InnoDB data, logs, and system tablespaces into separate devices. See my earlier post [MySQL on SSD - what are the disadvantages?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58341/mysql-on-ssd-what-are-the-disadvantages/58375#58375)

You should also think about getting away from Barracuda. See my old post [innodb_file_format Barracuda](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14246/innodb-file-format-barracuda/14287#14287)

## UPDATE 2014-12-07 18:14 EST

If you want to interrupt an InnoDB purge of everything and you don't want to preserve the data being fixed up, your only option is to set InnoDB Recovery Options. See my post [The InnoDB log sequence number is in the future](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44841/the-innodb-log-sequence-number-is-in-the-future/44884#44884). If you use the [**innodb_force_recovery**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_force_recovery) options, it may not let you do any more writes of InnoDB. If you a moderate amount of data, you could mysqldump whatever data can come out, shutdown mysqld, delete all data folders (except mysql schema), ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1, and ibdata1, start up mysql, reload data.

I cannot really help you if you have 1TB in a forced recovered state.

Comment: SAS and RAID10 aren't an option. SAS drives have extremely limited space, my money is limited (and consistently SAS drives are expensive) and RAID10 takes too many drives.

Comment: Now when the Server is in the shutdown process, there's no way to tell it to apply new settings through re-reading config or, if the cvar allows, change the setting on-the-fly ? At least so it seems to me. You imply that if I force the Server to die, logs and other mentioned files are unfinished or even corrupted, equaling to bad idea.

Comment: As I understand it, changing the IO threads count to 64 on quad-core (octa-thread) would kill performance altogether.

Comment: I had a client with dual hexacore, 162GB Buffer Pool, 64 read and write I/O threads. The default for Percona server is 8. If you are satisfied with that, don't use.

Comment: I said in the beginning of my answer `Unfortunately, you have to let InnoDB purge all its moving parts (Redo Logs, Undo Logs, Dirty Pages, Index Changes, Log Buffer Contents, etc)`

Comment: If I don't let it ?